# "Рыболовная сумка" или "рыбацкая сумка"? Почему?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно сказать: "рыболовная сумка" или "рыбацкая сумка"? Почему?
Заранее признателен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно товарищ Fuchoin Kazuki говорит. "Рыбацкая" - относящаяся к рыбаку. "Рыболовная" - для рыбного лова.

Рыбак - это прежде всего человек, и сумка ему может понадобиться для разных человеческих целей (носить вещи), но при этом иметь уклон в сторону его рода деятельности (например - быть герметичной и/или плавучей).

Рыбный лов - это прежде всего промысел, и "рыболовная сумка", по моим ощущениям, предназначена для него напрямую. У меня при словосочетании "рыболовная сумка" в голове всплывает образ какой-то хрени, которую бросают в воду по типу невода, и таким образом ловят ею рыбу.

Сравни с "рыболовная сеть" (сеть, которой ловят рыбу) и "рыбацкая сеть" (сеть рыбака). Вроде эквивалентно, но если говорить о менее рыбных вещах, то "рыбацкий посёлок" (посёлок рыбаков) - это нормально, а вот "рыболовный посёлок" (посёлок, с помощью которого ловят рыбу?) - уже как-то не так. При этом "посёлок рыболовов" - это нормально, но здесь "рыболовов" - это существительное, а не прилагательное (в отличие от "рыболовный").

Answer (score 0):

Это разные по смыслу вещи. Рыбацкая сумка принадлежит рыбаку, а рыболовная - предназначена для рыбной ловли.

Comment: Все равно не могу разобраться.

В конкретном примере как правильно сказать?

"Универсальная поясная рыболовная сумка Rapala Sling Bag Big."

Comment: Одно слово - от слова "рыбак", другое - от слова "рыболов".  Никакой разницы.

Comment: А может я и не прав... У рыболова была бы рыболовецкая.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе рыбак и рыболов - почти синонимы, поэтому и разница тут скорее стилистическая.
Я думаю, сумка скорее рыбацкая, если речь идёт о конкретном рыбаке-индивидуале. Если же это просто сумка для рыбной ловли, возмжожно даже групповой или промышленной, то - рыболовная. В вашем примере, думаю - рыбацкая, поскольку универсальная, т.е. должна служить не только для рыбной ловли но и для сопутствующих нужд отдельно взятого рыбака.